# error al pasar variable php con ajax

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax, menú

Mi problema es el siguiente tengo un menú `BOOSTRAP` donde el contenido lo extraigo de una base de datos `mysql`, siendo que al seleccionar una opción cargo el contenido de una página en un campo `div` de id central. Cuando hago la selección ya estoy en sesión  y tengo unas variables extraída de la `BD` que las mando por el método `GET` y la variable llega perfectamente, el problema se presenta es en la selección de nuevas variables que están en el menú porque no llegan al `div` central.
Para explicarme mejor coloco partes del `script` en el código `AJAX` :

```
$('#div-btn5').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "clases.php?ci=<?php echo  $assoc_prosesar['ci'];  ?>&idTema=<?php echo $modulo['idTema']; ?>",                  
       success: function(a) {
          $('#central').html(a);
       }
    });
});
```

**Código del menú es el siguiente:**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Ver Clases<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li  class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <?php
                     $busqUsuario="SELECT * FROM $tabla4 WHERE idalumno='$ci'"; //matricula
                     $resultUsuario = mysqli_query($db, $busqUsuario) or die(mysql_error());
                  ?>      
                  <?php 
                    if ($cursoUsuario=mysqli_fetch_array($resultUsuario)){ 

                       do { 
                           $idCurso=$cursoUsuario['idCurso'];
                           $busqCurso="SELECT * FROM $tabla3 WHERE id='$idCurso'"; //curso
                           $resultCurso = mysqli_query($db, $busqCurso) or die(mysql_error());
                           $curso=mysqli_fetch_array($resultCurso);
                 ?>
                  <a href="#" class="test" ><?php echo $curso['curso']; ?><span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                     <?php
                        $busqModulo="SELECT * FROM $tabla5 WHERE curso='$idCurso'"; //modulo
                        $resultModulo = mysqli_query($db, $busqModulo) or die(mysql_error());

                        if ($modulo=mysqli_fetch_array($resultModulo)){ 
                           do {
                               $idTemaSession=$modulo['idTema'];
                               if($modulo['cargado']=='SI'){
                               $busqCurso="SELECT * FROM $tabla11 WHERE id='$idCurso'"; //curso
                               $resultCurso = mysqli_query($db, $busqCurso) or die(mysql_error());
                               $curso=mysqli_fetch_array($resultCurso);
            ?>
              <li><a  href="#" id="div-btn5" ><?php  $e= addslashes($modulo['tema']); $codificadoe = utf8_encode($e); echo $codificadoe;?></a></li>
            <?php }
        } while ($modulo=mysqli_fetch_array($resultModulo)); 
    }
?>      
          </ul>
           <?php
             } while ($cursoUsuario=mysqli_fetch_array($resultUsuario)); 
              }
           ?>
            </li>
         </ul>
     </li>
```

En una publicación de un problema de esta página vi un ejemplo donde modificaban `href="#"` por `href="?ci=<?php echo  $assoc_prosesar['ci'];  ?>&idTema=<?php echo $modulo['idTema']; ?>"` pero no me funciono. espero me puedan ayudar y de ante mano doy las gracias por el tiempo dedicado a este problema.

Comment: Podrías ser mas especifico en que variables son las que no te salen?

Comment: Pero ¿qué son `$assoc_prosesar` y `$modulo`? ¿Esos datos no se recogen en alguna parte del lado del cliente? ¿Por qué usas variables PHP (servidor) ahí? No llego a entender la forma en que tienes organizado tu código. Tampoco entiendo por qué haces una consulta a la BD y luego otra, además dentro de un bucle. ¿Acaso tus tablas no están relacionadas? ¿Por qué no las unes mediante `JOIN` y haces una sola consulta? En cualquier caso, convendría que expliques mejor el contexto, sospecho que no tienes el código debidamente planteado en varios puntos.

Comment: La idea es que cuando un usuario inicie sesión desde el menú pueda seleccionar todas las opciones que están en la base de datos. En este caso se refiere a un alumno que esta en la tabla usuarios que se encuentra en el array   $assoc_prosesar y el contenido de la clase esta en el array $modulo la idea es que cuando se cargue en el div central llegue la variable con el método GET, el bucle tiene como objetivo presentar todos los cursos que están en la base de datos, hasta este momento todo esta bien lo único es que las variables no llegan al div o llegan vacías

Comment: Andres las variables son las que estan en el script Ajax ci e idTema, donde la ci llega al div pero idTema no llega o llega vacía

Comment: lo último que comentas que no te funcionó, lo del href, ¿en cuál de los dos href lo pusiste? debería ir en el segundo. por cierto, ese segundo siempre tiene el mismo id, cosa que no es correcta ya que debe ser único

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar variables a través de ajax debes utilizar el valor `data`. **Yo en mi caso utilicé el metodo POST**

```
$('#div-btn5').click(function(){
    var ci_v=<?php echo  $assoc_prosesar['ci'];  ?>;
    var id_tema_v=<?php echo $modulo['idTema']; ?>;
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "clases.php",
       data: {ci:ci_v,id_tema_v:id_tema},                  
       success: function(a) {
          $('#central').html(a);
       }
    });
});
```

Y en `clases.php` proceso la información

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
    $ci=$_POST['ci'];
    $id_tema=$_POST['id_tema'];
}
```

**En cuanto al href:**

A mi me funciono poniendo todo en un echo. Ejemplo:

```
$ci=$assoc_prosesar['ci'];
$id_tema=$modulo['idTema'];
$e= addslashes($modulo['tema']);
$codificadoe = utf8_encode($e);
echo('<a  href="clases.php?ci='.$ci.'&id_tema='.$id_tema.'" id="div-btn5" >'.$codificadoe.'</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar variables por ajax, yo lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
function Enviar(){
    var cod = document.getElementById("cod").value;
        var parametros = {
                "valor" : cod
        };

        $.ajax({
                data:  parametros,
                url:   '../RecibiendoDatos/index.php',
                type:  'post',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#msj").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                },
                success:  function (response) {             
                    $("#msj").html(response);
                }
        });

}
```

Supongamos que tienes un input:

`<input type="text" id="cod" name="cod"/>`

lo que hacemos es obtener lo que tiene ese input con javascript, y ya la respuesta del archivo php depende de lo que quieras responder, ya sea un mensaje o contenido html.